# Asycn interation in python loop with spreadsheets

Tags: python, google-sheets

__Hello! I'm using Google API. And I have a dictionary with, for example, 10 keys.
And I have 12 columns, which two of them are empty. I created a loop (for key in dic) and if statement where check empty columns. And this is a problem, because my values are dismissed.

```
for key in dic:
    userTimelist = [[]]
    i = 0
    row = dic[key]
    monthUser_range = "Everyday!" + str(row) + str(col_from) +  ":" + str(row) + str(col_to) #A109:A142, B109:B142, C109:C142, ...
    read_data_list = read_data(monthUser_range)
    # Passing inactive users
    if read_data_list == []:
        pass
    else:
        userTimelist[i].append(key)
        userTimelist[i].append(read_data_list)
        userTimelist[i].append(yesterday_time(dic[key]))
        print(userTimelist[i])
        structure.append(userTimelist[i])         
        i+=1
```

The empty columns are in the middle of whole array. And I have no idea, for example, how to merge two ranges without these two empty columns. Or maybe, Is there another beautiful solution?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `The empty columns are in the middle of whole array. And I have no idea, for example, how to merge two ranges without these two empty columns.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample value of `dic` and the sample input and output situations you expect as the image?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of your spreadsheet so the issue statement can be better understood?